# How to remove EPSON Projector Audio driver?

Tags: preferences, driver, macos

I made the mistake of installing the EPSON Projector Audio driver. It gets selected all the time, now, even when there is no EPSON Projector around. There's no obvious way to get rid of it. How do I make it go away?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to */Library/Extensions* and delete the "EPSONProjectorAudio.kext" kernel extension. The pesky EPSON Projector Audio driver should be gone after reboot.

(If you can't see the Library folder on your hard drive, try *Finder > Go > Go to folder…* and paste */Library/Extensions*)

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, note that the folder name is actually EMP_UDAU.kext. Once you delete this folder and reboot your Mac, the EPSON projector audio option is gone from the system.

Comment: Thank you epson!  EMP probably stands for something completely non-obvious, like Epson Media Player...

Answer (score 2):

Also to remove the toolbar app, search for "usb display uninstaller" in Spotlight.
Start the app and confirm uninstall (you will be asked to restart the computer).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6778963

> Go to Finder and select your user/home folder. With that Finder window as the front window, either select Finder/View/Show View options or go command - J.  When the View options opens, check ’Show Library Folder’. That should make your user library folder visible in your user/home folder.  Select Library/Audio. See if the driver is there.
>
> Also check the hard drive level Library/Audio.

Comment: Sadly, it is not there.